# Laravel Grouping Middleware With Same Route Problem

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6.2

I have 3 middlewares : middleware a ,b and c.

Then in routes/web.php , i define a URL like this.

```
Route::middleware(['a','b','c']->group(function () { 
Route::get('/a','TestController@index')->name('test.test'); });
```

when im login with all accounts , it said this page isn't redirecting properly.

I want access same url with different middleware, is it possible ?

And im already tried using this:

```
Route::middleware(['a' OR 'b' OR 'c']->group(function () { Route::get('/a','TestController@index')->name('test.test'); });
```

I think it was worked and solved. But,it's not. URL can be accessed by everyone and its ignore the middleware.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: you have to combine all 3 middle ware condition into one then write a logic what you need

Comment: i dont get it. may u give simple example or explanation sir ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the group like this to combine all middleware in one.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['a', 'b', 'c']], function() {
  Route::get('/a','TestController@index')->name('test.test'); });
});
```

You may also use it like this

```
Route::get('/a', function () {
 // Your stuff
})->middleware('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Comment: it's still not works sir, when only one middleware define, it works, but when i add more middlewares, its always redirected to the default url, and no middlewares can access that, why is this happen?

Comment: can you please show me your middleware's code, test all middlewares one by one and check they are working individually or not?

Comment: See the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-group-middleware

Comment: All of my middleware is like this. just differents on roles id.

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    { if ($this->auth->guest()) {
         if ($request->ajax()) {
             return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
         } else {
             return redirect()->guest('/');
         }
     }
     else if($this->auth->user()->roles_id != 1){
       return redirect('/')->with('failed','Anda tidak punya hak akses');
     }
     return $next($request);
    }

Comment: are you using resource controller?

Comment: im not sir, i define one by one. not using resource.

Comment: first make sure you have defined the middleware class in protected $middlewareGroups array.

Comment: If you have done that, then please use the middleware in constructor of your controller. Because you have auth in your controller so make sure you are using $this->middleware('auth'); first then pass other routes in other 2 middlewares.

Comment: Please go through this url, sure will help you !! https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware